# How do you get the internal drive to show up when you're reinstalling?

Tags: time-machine, install

Macbook Pro.  Trying to reinstall Yosemite.  I can get to the "Install OS X" page, but the only destination given is "Recovery HD".  I can go to disk utilities and see that "Macintosh HD" is there, and I can hit the "Verify Disk" and "Repair Disk" options and those run through with no errors.  The partition map shows one partition covering the entire disk (449.42G) with a Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" format.

How do I actually install to "Macintosh HD" though, if it doesn't show up as something you can install to?

Comment: Was your disk encrypted?, how did you prep it for the install? From where are you trying to install the Yosemite ? If you trying to Reinstall the it comes from the Recovery HD.

Comment: Yes, the disk at one point was encrypted.  I'm not sure what you mean by "how did you prep it for the install" - what sort of preps are there?  And I don't care how I do the install, if there's a better option I can certainly switch to it.

Comment: By prep, I believe he meant, did you erase the drive or reformat it before trying to install 10.10?  If the drive is encrypted, that is probably why you aren't able to install to it.  If you can, erase/reformat the hard drive and then you should be able to install 10.10.  You may have to remove the encryption first, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The comments about encryption pointed me in the right direction.

[Can you reinstall OS X on a FileVault 2-encrypted drive?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54177/can-you-reinstall-os-x-on-a-filevault-2-encrypted-drive) has the answer; you need to erase the drive first, and you need to do it from a terminal.

Use `diskutil cs list` to get the UUID of the `Logical Volume Group`. It's the first listed:

```
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
    |
    +-- Logical Volume Group BE3F9C36-A105-4854-9A5B-79511B0303B5
        =========================================================
        Name:         System
        Status:       Online
        Size:         67859718144 B (67.9 GB)
        Free Space:   12656640 B (12.7 MB)
        |
        +-< Physical Volume 9BB1A946-B429-47D0-970B-99CD78D8E502
        |   ----------------------------------------------------
        |   Index:    0
        |   Disk:     disk1s2
        |   Status:   Online
        |   Size:     67859718144 B (67.9 GB)
        |
        +-> Logical Volume Family F3AB68B3-6831-4BEA-B509-B1BF97DFC65E
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            Encryption Status:       Unlocked
            Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
            Conversion Status:       Complete
            Conversion Direction:    -none-
            Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
            Fully Secure:            Yes
            Passphrase Required:     Yes
            |
            +-> Logical Volume 4B5B7F22-9113-4813-B5B6-FF1C1117F0B9
                ---------------------------------------------------
                Disk:                  disk2
                Status:                Online
                Size (Total):          67494739968 B (67.5 GB)
                Conversion Progress:   -none-
                Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
                LV Name:               System
                Volume Name:           System
                Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

then `diskutil cs delete UUID`

With the above example: `diskutil cs delete BE3F9C36-A105-4854-9A5B-79511B0303B5`

(If you're looking at the startup menu that has four options - Restore from Time Machine backup, Reinstall OS X, Get Help Online, Disk Utility - you're in the right place.  Terminal isn't one of the obvious options, it's on the Utilities menu at the top of the screen.)